# Can anyone explain these functions as I could not find any description in the official documentation

Tags: pandas, date

I am trying to learn how to use dateoffset functions in pandas. But there are few attributes that I do not understand as there is no description in the official documentation.

The attributes are:

pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.name

pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.nanos

pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.rule_code

It would be helpful if anyone could also give an example of its application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `name` and `rule_code` attributes allow you to use the offset in functions for simplicity instead of importing and initialising the class. as an example you could do

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd, Day, FY5253

x = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-03-31', freq=BMonthEnd())
```

since the `rule_code` of `BMonthEnd` is `'BM'` you could simply do

```
x = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-03-31', freq='BM')
```

the `nanos` attribute is the number of nano seconds in the time offset. it needs to be a fixed-frequency offset (something constant like a Day not a Business Day).

so for a day offset, the number of nano second would be `86400000000000` which is 24 hours